# How Can I create a full width svg rectangle background?

Tags: html, css, svg

Hi I´m totally new to svg and would like to create something like this:

[Both ways would be cool but I dont mind to use the easier one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoAHO.png)

This is my code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <div class="single-product">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img src="img/p1.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <h4>Lorem ipsum </h4>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: why SVG if it's a simple rectangle?

Comment: Like @TemaniAfif said, it's a bit overkill. The easiest way to use SVG is not to generate it on the fly but just create it with a program like Adobe illustrator and then load in that SVG.
I would recommend this article: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Answer (score 0):

Use Adobe Illustrator to draw your object then save it as an SVG and you can copy the code paths that it gives you and it will generate it for you!

If you're just doing a rectangle though you don't need to use an svg you can use css surely?

https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/illustrator/how-to/export-svg.html

Answer (score 0):

use HTML5 tags

`<svg width="400" height="180">
  <rect x="50" y="20" rx="20" ry="20" width="150" height="150"
  style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5" />
</svg>`

Answer (score 0):

Using the viewBox attribute without width & height on the SVG will ensure it scales to 100% of available space.

To achieve something like the 2nd option in your linked example, you could position your SVG absolutely so that it sits behind a list of images.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.svgcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: grey;
}

.items {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 33%;
  text-align: center;
}
.item img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="svgcontainer">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 30">
    <path d="M93.8993 12C77.8993 -0.49999 -0.600744 -3.99999 0.899285 9C4.39923 32.5 43 26 70 26C97 26 97.7998 15.0473 93.8993 12Z" fill="currentcolor"/>
  </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="items">
    <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```